# Lua script Activation Key editing

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Can anyone help to change local Macro_Activation_Key = to capslock on = ak47 capslock off = m4a1 ?
Is it possible to add on this script ?

Here is the link: [LUA Script add Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171597/lua-script-add-delay/63819872#63819872)

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

`Selection_Key` removed, weapon now is selected by capslock

```
-- capslock on  = ak47 
-- capslock off = m4a1
local Macro_Activation_Key = 4    -- mouse button for turning macro on/off

-- d = delay to wait before moving the mouse (d=9 by default)
local AK47_Pattern = {{x=0,y=2},{d=11,x=0,y=2},{d=12,x=0,y=2},{x=0,y=3},{x=0,y=4},{x=0,y=4},{x=0,y=5},{x=0,y=8},{x=0,y=8},{x=0,y=8}} 
local M4A1_Pattern = {{x=0,y=1},{d=5,x=0,y=1},{d=7,x=0,y=2},{x=0,y=2},{x=0,y=1},{x=0,y=1},{x=0,y=2},{x=0,y=2},{x=0,y=3},{x=0,y=3},{x=0,y=3},{x=0,y=3},{x=0,y=3},{x=0,y=3},{x=0,y=3},{x=-1,y=4},{x=-1,y=4},{x=0,y=5},{x=-1,y=5},{x=-1,y=5},{x=0,y=5},{x=0,y=5},{x=0,y=5}} 

local function OutputLogs(s)
   OutputLogMessage(s.."\n")
   OutputDebugMessage(s.."\n")
   ClearLCD()
   OutputLCDMessage(s)
end 

local Recoil_Activator

function OnEvent(event, arg) 
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == Macro_Activation_Key then
      Recoil_Activator = not Recoil_Activator 
      OutputLogs(Recoil_Activator and "ON_Macro" or "OFF_Macro") 
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Recoil_Activator then
      local pattern = IsKeyLockOn("capslock") and AK47_Pattern or M4A1_Pattern
      for i = 1, #pattern do 
         Sleep(pattern[i].d or 9) 
         MoveMouseRelative( pattern[i].x, pattern[i].y ) 
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then 
            break
         end 
      end 
   end 
end
```

Comment: thank you sir @Egor Skriptunoff