# lua script problem in windows 2004 version

Tags: lua, windows-10, logitech-gaming-software

Lua scripts does not work properly in windows 10 2004 version.
Is there any way to fix it ?

My scripts are broken on windows 2004 version.
Its working 1909 or lower.

Scripts delays not working same as 1909 version.

Comment: So, `Sleep()` works differently?  Please note that 15 ms is the best precision you can get from `Sleep` in LGS/GHUB.  If you're using something like `Sleep(1)` or `Sleep(5)` the delay interval could be 15 ms sometimes instead.  It does not depend on Windows version.

Comment: So, use `Sleep(15)` and tune `y` in your recoil sequence.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821183/lua-script-activation-key-editing this script delays are not working on 2004.Coordinates are same but delays not working

Comment: What means "not working"?

Comment: i am doing 9 ms delay its not effecting at my script.Pattern is working but delays are not working correctly.It was working on 1909 version.But not working on windows 10 2004 version.

Comment: Use always 15 ms, that would be safe.